# JS - How to deal with space in file names?

Tags: javascript, html, encoding

Adding a space to a filename breaks the code.
This works:

```
<html>
<img id="window-1" src="http://url.net/demo1.png">
<img id="window-2" src="http://url.net/demo2.png">

<script>
    const content = { uid: 'image-1', uri: 'http://url.net/demo1.png' };
    const mediaWindows = [document.getElementById('window-1'), document.getElementById('window-2')];

    function getPlayedWindow(playedContent) {
        return mediaWindows.find((window) => window.src === playedContent)
    }

    console.log(getPlayedWindow(content.uri));        
            
</script>
```

This doesn't, the function returns undefined:

```
<html>
<img id="window-1" src="http://url.net/demo 1.png">
<img id="window-2" src="http://url.net/demo 2.png">

<script>
    const content = { uid: 'image-1', uri: 'http://url.net/demo 1.png' };
    const mediaWindows = [document.getElementById('window-1'), document.getElementById('window-2')];

    function getPlayedWindow(playedContent) {
        return mediaWindows.find((window) => window.src === playedContent)
    }

    console.log(getPlayedWindow(content.uri));        
            
</script>
```

I tried playing with JSON.stringify, no luck.

What am I missing?

EDIT: Not a duplicate, the question is about spaces. pointing to the possible duplication actually provides an answer, but one can't know that without asking first.

Comment: `http://url.net/demo%201.png` use like this

Comment: `window.src === encodeURI(playedContent)` A better way to deal with whitespace in filenames is to not have it in the first place ;)

Comment: The `arrays` tag does not seem to be related to the problem. Also, there are parts of your code that are not clear to be related to the problem. Please edit these out.

Comment: Also, your question doesn't make it clear whether the problem is happening in the HTML also or only the JavaScript.

Comment: @ChrisG file names are dynamic and uploaded by users, so can't assure not using them

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`encodeURI(content.uri)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURI) to ensure that the string is correctly encoded as a URI and will match what you see in `window.src` (the HTML is URI-encoded automatically to make it a valid URL). Ideally, stick to legal URIs and avoid the issue.

```html
<html>
<img id="window-1" src="http://url.net/demo 1.png">
<img id="window-2" src="http://url.net/demo 2.png">

<script>
    const content = { uid: 'image-1', uri: 'http://url.net/demo 1.png' };
    const mediaWindows = [document.getElementById('window-1'), document.getElementById('window-2')];

    function getPlayedWindow(playedContent) {
        return mediaWindows.find((window) => window.src === playedContent)
    }

    console.log(getPlayedWindow(encodeURI(content.uri)));        

</script>
```

Here's a minimal illustration of exactly what's going on:

```js
const uri = "http://url.net/demo 1.png";

console.log("from document:", document.querySelector("img").src); 
console.log("unencoded string URI:", uri); 
console.log("encoded string URI:", encodeURI(uri));
```

```html
<img src="http://url.net/demo 1.png">
```

Answer (score 0):

Whitespace is url encoded with '%20'. You can encode whitespace in javascript with 'encodeURI' or 'encodeURIComponent'.

Comment: not encodeURICompoment - that messes up the `/` for a start

Answer (score 0):

Use encodeURI

```js
const content = { uid: 'image-1', uri: 'http://url.net/demo 1.png' };
    const mediaWindows = [document.getElementById('window-1'), document.getElementById('window-2')];

    function getPlayedWindow(playedContent) {
        return mediaWindows.find((window) => window.src === encodeURI(playedContent))
    }

    console.log(getPlayedWindow(content.uri));
```

```html
<img id="window-1" src="http://url.net/demo 1.png">
<img id="window-2" src="http://url.net/demo 2.png">
```